# Invalid segment Alignment. Windows 8

Tags: ios, flash, air

i am using windows 8.0, adobe flash professional CC and AIR SDK 14 to develop my app.

I am submitting my ipa file to appstore through application loader.

i got an error message

ERROR ITMS-9000:"Inavalid segment alignment. this app does not have proper segment alignment and should be rebuilt with the latest version of Xcode Please contact Developer Technical Support if you need further assistence."

There is a solution for mac users https://forums.adobe.com/message/6763023#6763023
But how to solve this issue on windows PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your AIR SDK and re-compile it again.
Here is the link http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html. Select your version.

Actual version is 15.0.0.302 from the Labs. It contain a lot of iOS8 fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for Adobe to resolve this issue too...seems like the air linker in air 15 is outdated
and no longer accepted by apple.

Comment: p.s. my app is developed in flashdevelop on win8

Comment: I tried with the air 14 also, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: i tried even with air 13, because it support older architecure, no luck...seems like we are doomed to wait for adobes response...